How does flutter achieve iOS style photo gallery zoom effect
How can one make a dynamic GridView.builder using Flutter where the user can zoom in and out to change the number of columns of the grid such as the iOS Photo Gallery app.
like this: eg
my code is here
class MyApp2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp2({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp2> createState() => _MyApp2State();
}

class _MyApp2State extends State<MyApp2> {
  int _pointersCount = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Listener(
          onPointerDown: (_) => setState(() => _pointersCount++),
          onPointerUp: (_) => setState(() => _pointersCount--),
          child: InteractiveViewer(
            child: GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 9,
                mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
              ),
              physics: _pointersCount == 2
                  ? const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
                  : null,
              itemCount: 5000,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    '${index + 1}',
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

